# PostgreSQL : Converting timestamp without time zone to a specific timezone not working

Tags: database, postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to migrate a column in Postgres from `Timestamp without time zone` to a `timestamp with time zone`. I want to do it for German time, so I used the following query :

```
alter table table_name alter column uploaddate type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE USING uploaddate at time zone 'UTC+01:30';
```

Unfortunately it's not working, it's adding `2015-06-30 07:30:48.785+05:30`. I am currently in India, which is +5.30. How can I specify to the query to do it with German time zone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the timezone of the timestamps stored in the table? That is, if there is a value such as `2016-09-22 07:30` in the table, in what timezone is `07:30`? This is the timezone that you want to use, not your current local timezone. So e.g. if all timestamps are expressed in german timezone you should do something like:

```
alter table table_name
alter column uploaddate type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
USING uploaddate at time zone 'Europe/Berlin';
```

Don't forget that you can run the above inside a transaction so that you can inspect the results before you commit them (of course this will lock the entire table and block all other concurrent queries for that table).

Comment: How can I confirm this, as even after doing this, it shows me +5.30. I have backup, so I am just replacing it.

Comment: You mean that _after_ the conversion, if you run a select query, it will print a +5.30 offset? If that is the case, that is not a problem, this has only to do with how `psql` _prints_ the timestamps, not with how postgresql _stores_ them. You can do `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` and then all subsequent queries in the same session will print timestamps in their textual representations in german time.

Comment: Just one last question, how can I see the timestamp set in either pgadmin or via PSQL?

Comment: You can simply run the query `SHOW TIME ZONE;`'

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.